# NSString "initWithBytesNoCopy:length:encoding:freeWhenDone:" may modify input "bytes"?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, nsstring, const-correctness

```
- (id)initWithBytesNoCopy:(void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding freeWhenDone:(BOOL)flag
```

"bytes" is not a const pointer. Does it mean this method may modify "bytes"?

Comment: bytes is not a const pointer. At least I see no "const" in that method declaration.

Comment: @WTP -- that's what he said.  Why is it not const?

Comment: If freeWhenDone = YES, it not only may modify the characters, it may even call free (). Once you call the method, the characters are not yours anymore, so whether they get modified or not is none of your business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assume that it may mutate since that is the signature and there is not documentation that otherwise negates that.

So my answer is: It is because the `SEL`'s signature does not/cannot change for `NSMutableString`s that it is declared non-const.

Here are some `NSString` creation alternatives which suggest a little more safety without copy:

- `CFStringCreateWithBytesNoCopy`
- `CFStringCreateWithCStringNoCopy`
- `CFStringCreateWithCharactersNoCopy`

Chances are good that the `NSString` APIs in question also use these.

CF-APIs provide more appropriate functions for mutable variants, e.g. `CFStringCreateMutableWithExternalCharactersNoCopy`, and these are likely what `NSMutableString` would use.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, as @WTP says, bytes is not declared `const` so yes, it *could*

In reality - no. Why would it?

Are you seeing a bug in your app where it does?

If you're planning to be paranoid, why don't you make a copy of bytes before calling this method?

Comment: One does wonder, then, what the difference is between the regular and "NoCopy" versions.  It's not obvious from the spec.

Comment: In this case I guess it's implicit that you woudldn't want to change the value of bytes so they haven't bothered with const. Personally, I would have put it in there just to be clear what the intention of the method was. And there isn't a 'regular' and 'no copy' version - if you want it to work off a copy, you have to do the copying yourself (i.e. with memcpy).

Comment: When I look at the NSString spec I see both `initWithBytes:length:encoding:` and `initWithBytesNoCopy:length:encoding:freeWhenDone:`.  How is the second different from the first (given that "freeWhenDone" makes no sense with the first)??

Comment: Oh, sorry - I was thinking about NSData, not NSString (I should  have read the question more carefully!) In that case I guess the first one would copy the data internally, the second one would just use the data you gave it. The first one would meean that you could `free` your data immediately after calling it, the second one would mean that you had to remember to `free` your data when you were finished with the string. Use the first one - it would nake your life much much easier!

Comment: Except that an NSString is nominally 16-bit characters, so it's hard to see how retaining the original byte string would be of any use.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: I.e., the difference is that the version without `NoCopy` makes its own copy. It then has its own buffer containing copies of the bytes in your buffer, so you can free your buffer whenever you want without breaking the string. The `NoCopy` version uses the buffer you gave it, so if you free that buffer before the string, the string will probably fail in some way later. It also means that you can change the contents of your buffer to change the string, whereas the copying version would still the bytes (in its copy) that you originally gave it.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: An NSString presents an interface of 16-bit characters, but is neither guaranteed nor required not to have internal storage in any other encoding. The 16-bit characters may be converted from any other encoding on demand, or the string may maintain two storage buffers in two encodings (perhaps lazily creating one). If you were to create an NSString from, say, UTF-8, then get bytes in the same encoding from it later, it would be an efficiency win for it never to generate the UTF-16.